# Solution Verification: Find the mass of $V$. (Triple integral)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

> We define $V=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2+z^2\le z$ } 
> Mass Density is given by $g(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ , 
> Find the Mass of $V$.

**My Work:**
So I need to find $I=\iiint_{V}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}dxdydz$, and in order to do that, I will move to spherical coordinations: 
$x=rsin\phi cos\theta$ 
$y=rsin\phi sin\theta$ 
$z=rcos\phi$.
And so $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2\le z = rcos\theta \Longrightarrow r\le cos\theta \Longrightarrow -\frac{\pi}{2} \le\theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ ($cos\theta \ge 0)$. 
and so there's no restrictions on $0 \le \phi \le \pi$. and $0 \le r\le cos\theta$. 
So: 
$$I=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int^{cos\theta}_{0}r.r^2sin\phi drd\phi d\theta=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}[\int_0^{\pi}\frac{cos^4\theta}{4}sin\phi ]d\phi d\theta=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}[\int^{\pi}_0\frac{1+cos^2(2\theta)}{2}sin\phi]d\phi d\theta = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}[\int^{\pi}_0\frac{3+cos(4\theta)}{4}sin\phi]d\phi d\theta = \frac{1}{4} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}[\int^{\pi}_0(3sin\phi+cos(4\theta)sin\phi)]d\phi d\theta = \frac{1}{4} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}[(\pi3sin\phi+sin(4\pi)sin\phi)]d\phi d\theta = \frac{1}{4} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}[(\pi3sin\phi)]d\phi=\frac{3}{4}\pi (-cos(-\pi) - cos(\pi))=\frac{6\pi}{4}$$I would really appreciate any feedback about my solution, even the smallest mistakes, and would love to get an approval of my answer, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct but you have a mistake in your work.

$V=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2+z^2\le z\}$

As you defined $x = \rho \cos\theta \sin\phi, y = \rho \sin\theta \sin\phi, z = \rho \cos\phi$

$x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq z \implies \rho \leq \cos\phi, 0 \leq \phi \leq \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

So the integral should be,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\cos\phi} \rho^3 \sin\phi \ d\rho \ d\phi \ d\theta = \frac{\pi}{10}$

Comment: Thanks so much, such an annoying mistake to be honest, I will try to solve it again on a paper this time and reach the same answer as you

Comment: Update, I've reached an answer of $\frac{\pi}{8}-\frac{1}{15}$, I'm not sure where did I make a mistake, I've used $cos^2(a)=\frac{1+cos(2a)}{2}$ twice, and used $cos(a)sin(b)=\frac{sin(a+b)+sin(b-a)}{2}$ in the end to get my final answer, have you done the same or did I just make things difficult?

Comment: Just noticed that I can do it much easier $cos^5(x)'=-5cos^4(x)sin(x)$, and got $\frac{\pi}{10}$ as an answer.

Comment: @Pwaol sorry I did not see your message earlier. I had just used an online calculator but to do it manually, what you did now is a very good way to evaluate.